# Custom Market with text, Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have multiple markets in a map of Google for an Android Application
But what i want to have is the next icon as a market:

[image]

Depending of a list of elements I have. 
I being doing multiple of changes but the original code:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {

                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(points.get(i))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cutedot))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 1));
            }
```

Comment: does this code have a problem ? what happens when you run it ?

Comment: It only put the icon without the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only put the marker (i'm guessing there is no number in the drawable),

Try this

```
for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cutedot);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawText(i+"", textXOffset, textYOffset, mPictoPaint);
    MarkerOptions options = new     MarkerOptions().position(points.get(i)).anchor(0.5f,1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapResul    t    ));
    Marker newMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);

}
```